# Installing gems in Mac OS X pre-installed ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.8, ruby-1.8.7

Macs seem to all come with ruby 1.8.7 pre-installed. That's fine for my purposes, but when I install gems with either `gem install gem-name` or `sudo gem install gem-name`, I have to explicitly add the gem's lib directory to my $LOAD_PATH at the top of my ruby programs:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.join("/", "Users", "me", ".gems", "more_dirs", "lib")
```

Why do I have to do this? Am I installing gems wrong?

If I then install rvm and the latest ruby 1.9.3, I can install gems no problem with `gem install gem-name`.

Comment: my guess is that you first installed w/o sudo and it built gems in ~/.gems  And now since that exists and isn't your load path you have to add it.  try removing (moving) .gems,  then reinstall your gems with sudo gem install  and see if that puts them in the right place

Comment: @Doon - no I've tried first doing `sudo gem install`. You're right in that without sudo, gems will be install in `~/.gems`. With sudo, they're installed in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/`. Either way, I have to add to that $LOAD_PATH for all my gems at the beginning of all programs.

Comment: Do you have require 'rubygems' in your script? since that *should* add the gem loadpaths in?

Comment: @Doon - no I don't, I guess that was a requirement pre-1.9?

Comment: I think it  has always been a requirement. But I you are using something like rake or rails rubygems was probably already required at somepoint

Comment: @Doon - no even without rubygems or anything. If I have a 3-line ruby program that depends on a simple gem, in ruby 1.9.3, I only have to require that gem. This is both on Macs and PCs.

Comment: Yeah sorry brain fart. Forget 1.9 comes with ruby gems.

Comment: @Doon - I haven't had a chance to test out require 'rubygems', but you should make it your answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1):

With 1.8.7 where rubygems aren't built in. You need to

```
 require 'rubygems'
```

at the top of your scripts in order to avoid manually setting the paths to your gems (pulling this in from the comments)